# How to include two fonts with same name?

Tags: ios, fonts

I have two fonts with the same name (the two fonts have different ascender properties). How can I include both fonts in my project and use them? I am unable to figure out how to change the name of one of the fonts without installing Font Forge, which seems like a day long project. Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the fonts? Is there some reason the original creator/vendor/maker did not or cannot rename one for you?

Comment: @djangodude Source Sans Pro. I don't know how to contact the creator.

Comment: Source Sans Pro originated at Adobe and is available through several different webfont service providers. I'm just curious how you managed to obtain two different versions. At any rate: changing the ascender value is not terribly difficult, but Font Forge can be a challenge, not only to get installed but also to run without making other unintended changes to your font data (especially if you don't know what you're doing).

Comment: @djangodude I got one version, which I'm using, and then I duplicated it and changed the ascender properties to create the second version. So I have two copies now. I want to use both copies throughout my app in different locations - the only problem is that they have the same PostScript name, so I'm not sure how I should refer to each in my code.